# Bootstrap where button is not align

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have a problem as below code

```
<div className="row">
                  <div className="col-md-3">
                    <DateTimePickerComponent
                      id="dateFrom"
                      name="dateFrom"
                      placeholder="Date from"
                      
                    />
                    <div className="d-flex align-items-center error-container">
                      {searchForm.touched.dateFromError && Boolean(searchForm.errors.dateFromError) && (
                        <span className="text-danger small">{searchForm.errors.dateFromError}</span>
                      )}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-md-4">
                    <DateTimePickerComponent
                      id="dateTo"
                      name="dateTo"
                      placeholder="Date to"
                     
                    />
                    <div className="d-flex align-items-center error-container">
                      {searchForm.touched.dateFromError && Boolean(searchForm.errors.dateFromError) && (
                        <span className="text-danger small">{searchForm.errors.dateFromError}</span>
                      )}
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div className="col-md-4 d-flex align-items-center">
                    <DropDownListComponent
                      id="vouType"
                      dataSource={sessionLists}
                      
                    />
                    <Button variant="outlined">Detail</Button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

when I run it the the last one DropDownListComponent and button
currently is this
[image]

put it at middle and I want to vertical align with textbox which like this

can I know how to make it ?
and I would like to make this
[image]

Comment: your button is aligned in the vertical center, just check the boundaries in chrome/safari/firefox dev tools. the thing is, your boxes are higher than you think because of the labels on top.

Comment: This kind of problem is best presented as rendered HTML, not JSX. At a minimum, _tag_ React, but ideally put your HTML and CSS in a demo snippet using the editor. Present your problem before dumping your code on us. See [ask] for more tips.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While making responsive layout, based on your break-point col-md it align vertically. Adjust your column size like instead of using col-md-4 use col-sm-4.

And I am not clear about what is the problem you are facing. Sharing your resulting problem as a screenshot makes easier to analyse

Comment: Related: *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)*.